# Twice Linear Java

Tags: java

This is the problem I am trying to solve. I am not looking for an exact solution but only if someone could guide me how to solve.

Description:
Consider a sequence u where u is defined as follows:
The number u(0) = 1 is the first one in u.
For each x in u, then y = 2 * x + 1 and z = 3 * x + 1 must be in u too.
There are no other numbers in u.
Ex: u = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, ...]
1 gives 3 and 4, then 3 gives 7 and 10, 4 gives 9 and 13, then 7 gives 15 and 22 and so on…
Task:
Given parameter n the function dbl_linear (or dblLinear…) returns the element u(n) of the ordered (with <) sequence u.
Example:
dbl_linear(10) should return 22
Note:
Focus attention on efficiency

I have my own solution for the above problem but the solution breaks down when I have bigger index number as the input to the function dbl_linear. Like if the index number is 6000 or 10,000.

Here is my own solution which works for smaller ranges.

```
   public static int dblLinear (int n) {
       // your code
       System.out.println("the input range is " + n);
       ArrayList<Integer> possibleOutputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       //LinkedHashSet<Integer> possibleOutputsWithoutDuplicates = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
       possibleOutputs.add(1);
       for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
           int y = 2*possibleOutputs.get(i) + 1;
           int z = 3*possibleOutputs.get(i) + 1;

             if(!possibleOutputs.contains(y))
             {
               possibleOutputs.add(y);
             }
             if(!possibleOutputs.contains(z))
             {
               possibleOutputs.add(z);
             }

              //Collections.sort(possibleOutputs);
        }    
        //System.out.println(possibleOutputs);
        Collections.sort(possibleOutputs);
        //System.out.println(possibleOutputs);
        return possibleOutputs.get(n);
    }
```

Comment: *but the solution breaks down when I have bigger index number as the input to the function dbl_linear* it breaks down as in does what? throws any exception or results incorrect?

Comment: You can make it faster by using a `HashSet` instead of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld the code shows wrong results when I input bigger numbers. Also it takes too long to execute.

Comment: @nullpointer incorrect results. If u will compare the sorted and the unsorted list for say when the input is 100. The answer is supposed to be 447 but its not.

Comment: I see.  You are not generating your data in order.  You can generate `z=3*x+1`, and add that to your array, and then generate other values based on it before generating `y=2*x+1` on a smaller value.  As a result, your output array contains n valid values, before generating all u(x) values below u(n).

Comment: @AJNeufeld i think that might work. That might be in the right direction.

Comment: @SourabhPal In your sample `[1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, ` where is 21 generated from? if its not suppose to be generated, then what should be the output?

Comment: @AJNeufeld so u mean that i should generate both the linear values separately and then using combine them to get the final u(x) series?

Comment: You can't generate them separately; a y value can be generated from a z, and a z from a y.  But you can keep a sorted list of generated values, and generate new values from the smallest value which has not yet been used to generate values.

Comment: Thank you @AJNeufeld I will try your to use your suggestions to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, guiding you to the solution instead of giving you an exact solution:

You'll want to create the set `u()` in an already sorted order, instead of sorting it after the fact.  You'll want to use a `Set`, rather than a `List`, to make the adding of members without duplicating them trivial.

The most efficient sorted Set you can use would be the `BitSet`.

Start by initializing u(1) in the set, then...

Search for the next unprocessed u(x) value, and add u(2x+1) and u(3x+1) to the set.

Searching for the next unprocessed value is easy with [nextSetBit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit(int)).

For efficiency, you can stop generating u(x) values at a certain point.  Exact limit left as exercise to student.

Comment: I tried to implement using BitSet but there is no way i can return the value at a given Index. Its creating the right values and keeping them sorted but the only problem is that it's get() method only returns  a boolean value to tell whether the bit is set or not

Comment: `bitset.stream().skip(index).findFirst().getAsInt()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class DoubleLinear {
    public static int dblLinear (int n) {
        Integer x = 1;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        int listSize = 3;
        int maxtimes = n + (n/2);
        TreeSet<Integer> list = new TreeSet<>();
        list.add(1);
        while(listSize < maxtimes){
            y = 2*x+1;
            z = 3*x+1;
            if (list.add(y)){
                listSize++;
            }
            if (list.add(z)){
                listSize++;
            }
            counter++;
            x = new ArrayList<>(list).get(counter);
        }
        x = new ArrayList<>(list).get(n);
        return x;
    }
}
```

This is my best shot at the problem. The purpose is efficiency, but I can't figure out how to squeeze more out of it.